# Can't upgrade Gensim library to version 4 in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, gensim

I need to upgrade to the newest Gensim version. I ran `pip install --upgrade gensim` and I get `Requirement already satisfied.`

Then:

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 22:29:32) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gensim
>>> print(gensim.__version__)
3.8.3
```

I am running the pip install inside my conda environment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you take a look at the release history [here](https://pypi.org/project/gensim/#history), you will see that gensim version 4 is not yet relreased. However, you can upgrade to the pre release version using the `--pre` flag
so you can upgrade to gensim v4 using

```
pip install  --upgrade gensim --pre
```